# Проблема в реализации длинной арифметики (синтаксис)

Tags: c++

Проблема с перегруженным оператором -=, обычный "-" работает как надо, а вот -= не работает. + и += работают исправно. В чем проблема?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
#define BASE 1000000000
#define SIZE 600
using namespace std;

int CountOfDigits(ll X)
{
    if(X == 0 || X == 1) return 1;
    else return ceil(log10(X));
}

class BigInt
{
    private:
        ll digit[SIZE];
    public:

        BigInt()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                digit[i] = 0;   
        }       

        BigInt(string s)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                digit[i] = 0;
            int overallDigits = 0;
            ll currentPosition = s.size() - log10(BASE);
            ll temp = 0;
            while(currentPosition >= 1 - log10(BASE))
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < log10(BASE); i++)
                {
                    if(currentPosition + i >= 0) temp = temp * 10 + s[currentPosition + i] - 48;
                }
                currentPosition -= log10(BASE);
                digit[overallDigits++] = temp;
                temp = 0;
            }
        }

        BigInt(const BigInt& other)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                digit[i] = other.digit[i];
        }

        BigInt& operator=(const BigInt& other)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                digit[i] = other.digit[i];  
            return *this;
        }

        BigInt(ll X)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                digit[i] = 0;
            int overallDigits = 0;
            while(X)
            {
                digit[overallDigits++] = X % BASE;
                X /= BASE;
            }
        }

        BigInt operator+(const BigInt& other)
        {
            BigInt temp;
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
            {
                temp.digit[i] += (digit[i] + other.digit[i]) % BASE;
                temp.digit[i+1] += (digit[i] + other.digit[i]) / BASE;
            }
            return temp;
        }

        void operator +=(const BigInt& other)
        {
            *this = *this + other;
        }

        BigInt operator-(const BigInt& other)
        {
            BigInt temp;
            for(int i = SIZE; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                temp.digit[i] += digit[i] - other.digit[i];
                if(temp.digit[i] < 0)
                {
                    temp.digit[i] += BASE;
                    temp.digit[i+1]--;
                }
            }
            return temp;
        } 

        void operator -=(const BigInt& other)
        {
            *this = *this - other;
        }

        void print_digits()
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
                cout << digit[i] << " ";
        }

        void display()
        {
            ll overallDigits = 0;
            for(int i = SIZE - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if(digit[i])
                {
                    overallDigits = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            cout << digit[overallDigits]; 
            for(int i = overallDigits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                for(int j = 1; j <= log10(BASE) - CountOfDigits(digit[i]); j++) cout << "0";
                cout << digit[i];
            }
        }

};

int main()
{
    string first, second;
    cin >> first >> second;
    BigInt alpha = first, betta = second;
    alpha = alpha - betta; // работает
    // alpha -= betta (не работает)
    cout << endl;
    alpha.display();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Размер массива с разрядами равен SIZE, т.е. последний элемент SIZE - 1. А в цикле оператора "-" рассматривались все элементы от 0..SIZE включительно и получался выход за пределы массива..